# Why is the event handler capable of hijacking my direct call to eval?

Tags: javascript, eval, language-lawyer

I already know that, in an [event handler content attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes), the scope is shadowed by the element.

Therefore, in the snippet below, `(1,eval)` resolves to the custom `eval` property of the button, so the background becomes green instead of red.

```js
document.querySelector('button').eval = function(){ return 'green'; };
```

```html
<button onclick="document.body.style.background = (1,eval)('red')">Click me</button>
```

This behavior is defined in [step 10](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:script-execution-environment-2) of [getting the current value of the event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler) and makes sense.

But in the following snippet I use a reference named `eval`, so it should be a direct call to the native `eval`. However, the called function is the custom `eval` of the button, as if it were an indirect call:

```js
document.querySelector('button').eval = function(){ return 'green'; };
```

```html
<button onclick="document.body.style.background = eval('red')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: There's really not much difference between `eval()` and `(1,eval)()`

Comment: @Pointy `(1,eval)()` is always an indirect call and `eval()` is usually a direct call.

Comment: Ah OK, you're talking about the weird "is it really `eval`" rule. Got it. Still, in that context, the symbol `eval` is going to be the local one, which is of course what your answer says.

Comment: @Pointy All articles I read about direct calls to `eval` only mentioned that the reference name must be `"eval"`, but didn't say the reference must resolve to `%eval%`. So I was expecting it to behave in an "evil" way. The intuitive behavior surprised me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, in order to make a direct call to `eval`, using a reference named `eval` is not enough. The reference also needs to resolve to the built-in `eval`.

In ES5 this is explained in [15.1.2.1.1 - Direct Call to Eval](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1):

> A direct call to the eval function is one that is expressed as a
>   *CallExpression* that meets the following two conditions:
>
> - The [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) that is the result of evaluating the *MemberExpression* in the *CallExpression* has an environment record as its base value and its reference name is `"eval"`.
> - The result of calling the abstract operation [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) with that [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) as the argument is the standard built-in function
>     defined in [15.1.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1).

And in ES6 it's specified in [12.3.4.1 - Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> 1. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *MemberExpression*.
> 2. Let *func* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue)(*ref*).
> 3. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*func*).
> 4. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*ref*) is [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type) and [IsPropertyReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type)(*ref*) is **false** and
>      [GetReferencedName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type)(*ref*) is `"eval"`, then
>
>    1. If [SameValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevalue)(*func*, %eval%) is **true**, then

In fact, the event handler is unrelated. You would have the same problem if you overwrote the global `eval`.

```js
window.eval = function(){ return "green"; };
alert(eval('red')); // "green"
```